# If $C \subset B$ where $B$ is a bounded subset of a metric space $(X, d)$, then $C$ is bbd and $\operatorname{diam} C \leq \operatorname{diam} B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Prove that if $C \subset B$ where $B$ is a bounded subset of a metric space $(X, d)$, then $C$ is bounded and $\operatorname{diam} C \leq \operatorname{diam} B$

*My Attempted Proof*

Since $B$ is bounded $\exists \delta > 0$ and $x \in X$ such that $B \subseteq B_{(x, d)} (x, \delta)$

Given $C \subseteq B$ supose that $\text{diam} C > \operatorname{diam} B$. Trvially we have $\operatorname{diam} B \leq \delta$, hence $d(b_1, b_2) \le \delta$ for all $b_1, b_2 \in B$

If $\operatorname{diam} C > \operatorname{diam} B$, then there must exist $c_1, c_2 \in C$ such that $d(c_1, c_2) > d(b_1, b_2)$ for all $ b_1, b_2 \in B$, but since $C \subseteq B$ we have $c_1, c_2 \in B$ reaching a contradiction.

Therefore it follows that  $\operatorname{diam} C \leq \operatorname{diam} B$

Since $B$ is bounded we have $C \subseteq B \subseteq B_{(X, d)}(x, \delta)$ and hence $C$ is also bounded. $\ \ \square$

---

Is my proof correct? If so how rigorous is it? Are there points where it can be improved? Any comments on my proof style and writing are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It can be simplified: the diameter proof need not be done by contradiction.

$B$ is bounded so $B \subseteq B(x, R)$ for some $X \in X, R>0$. (no need for $(X,d)$ in the subscript, as this is clear by context).
Then also $C \subset B$ so the same $x$ and $R$ work to show $C$ is bounded.

Let $c_1, c_2 \in C$ then $d(c_1, c_2) \le \operatorname{diam}(B)$, as the latter number is by definition an upperbound for the set  $\{d(b_1, b_2): b_1, b_2 \in B\}$and $d(c_1, c_2)$ is one of those numbers (as $C \subset B$).
So $\operatorname{diam}(B)$ is an upperbound for $\{d(c_1,c_2): c_1,c_2 \in C\}$
and $\operatorname{diam}(C)$ is the by definition the smallest of these upperbounds, so $\operatorname{diam}(C) \le \operatorname{diam}(B)$

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show that

1. if $A\subset B$ so $\sup A\leq \sup B$
2. Show that $\{d(x,y)|x,y\in A\}\subset \{d(x',y')|x',y'\in B\}$
3. Let $\operatorname{diam} = \sup$ and use (1.) to show that $\operatorname{diam}(A) \leq \operatorname{diam}(B)$